# delete smallest node in a linked list

Tags: pointers, linked-list

I tried to write following function to delete the smallest node in a linked list. But, i am getting error and am not able to rectify it. please help.

error is -> Error   1   error C4703: potentially uninitialized local pointer variable 'trailSmall' used

here is my code:

```
void linkedListType<T>::deleteSmallest()
{
nodeType<T> *current;
nodeType<T> *trailCurrent;     // used for pointing to node just before current

nodeType<T> *small;
nodeType<T> *trailSmall;     

if (first == NULL)
    cout << "Cannot delete from an empty list." << endl;
else
    if (first->link == NULL)
    {
        first = NULL;
        delete last;
        last = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        small = first;
        trailCurrent = first;
        current = first->link;

        while (current != NULL)
        {
            if (small->info > current->info)
            {
                trailSmall = trailCurrent;
                small = current;
            }

            trailCurrent = current;
            current = current->link;
        }

        if (small == first)
            first = first->link;
        else if (small != first)
        {
            trailSmall->link = small->link;

            if (small == last)
                last = trailSmall;
        }

        delete small;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is (unusually) crystal clear: your code may read `trialSmall`, but does not always set it to anything.  But I think you are safe; the only time `trialSmall` is accessed is if you get the the non-trivial case, and further if `small != first` (which you don't need to test for explicitly, since you just determined that `small==first` isn't true); but the same place that `small` changes is where `trialSmall` changes.  (This is a pretty subtle thing for a compiler to catch.)

I'd just go ahead and initialize `trialSmall` to `first` to placate the compiler.

Comment: Thanks a lot, even I figured out that I have to initialize trailSmall somewhere, but I was unable to figure out as to what should I initialize it with. Silly mistake! thanks once again